# How to prepare iPhone app to be able for upgrading to the latest version available on AppStore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How to prepare app to be able for upgrading to the latest version available on AppStore

Comment: I don't understand what's asked here. Please describe your problem in more depth. What kind of preparations do you mean?

Comment: I am writing new application. CFBundleVersion parameter from info.plist file is set to 1.0. I am going to submit this app to AppStore. Soon I will add more functionality and would like to submit version 2.0 for example. How does all users who have already downloaded this application will get alert that there is a new version available? Would it be enough just to change CFBundleVersion to 2.0 and AppStore will do the rest? Or I have to implement some other stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While setting the CFBundleVersion is something I always do, the displayed app version and and upgrading is handled in iTunes Connect and not something you actually "prepare" from a code perspective.

a) Logon to iTunes Connect.

b) Choose "Manage Your Applications"

c) Click the app you want to upgrade

d) Click "Add Version" - this is where you will supply the version number

e) Fill out the information as you would with any app.

Once approved the upgrade availability is handled by the end user's iTunes and alerts them that an upgrade is available. I have yet to use it, but I believe Apple has added the ability to choose when an approved app is released.

Comment: Wow, great, I like this! Hope my boss will like it ;)